# make divs scale on height with css but no bootstrap on browser is resized

Tags: html, css

So lets imagine I have 6 div elements with different content.

3 divs are header

1 div is main container (scrollable)

last 2 divs are footer

How to make all of this scallable just with pure css? Because now when I'm resizing my browser my footer divs are just disappearing and I can't reach them and when I make my browser even smaller my main container div is cut in half (lower part disappears) and header divs height gets smaller

The best scenario would be to make header and footer divs somehow fixed height(don't know how) and main container to resize on broswer is resized.

html

```
<div ng-controller="ListController">
    <div class="header">

    </div>
    <div class="price_found">

    </div>
    <div class="settings">

    </div>
    <div class="main_container antiscroll-wrap">
        <div class="container antiscroll-inner">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="total_select">

    </div>
    <div class="menu_footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

scss

```
.cheap-watcher {  //this is main container properties in which everything is injected
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 360px;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f3f4;
    float: right;

    .header {
        height: 7.57%;
        background-color: #00a8e8;
    }

    .price_found {
        padding-top: 16px;
        height: 10.169%;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .settings {
        height: 4.971%;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }

     .main_container {
        width: 360px;
        background-color: #fff;

        .container {
            width: 360px;
            height: 57.856%;
        }
    }

    .total_select {        
        height: 7.57%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-top: solid;
        border-top-color: #e8e8e8;
        border-top-width: 2px;
    }

    .menu_footer {
        height: 11.864%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: @chsdk there's kinda a lot of code, so I update my question with divs and those divs css in a minute

Comment: Ok, you could just make a [**fiddle**](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign to all of your containers a `min-height` for example in `px` or `vh`. Min. Height means that the container will always have that minimum height but will grow as more content comes in. For your main container you obviously want a fixed height, so use normal `height` and use also `px` or `vh` and `overflow` so if you have more content then the height allows, the main container becomes scrollable.

See a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19332/)

Hope this helps you a bit.